# Making a Quadratic Roots project, my second set of nested "IF" statements is being ignored

Tags: c++, if-statement, nested

To quickly explain, I need six different possible cout outputs. Three for when A = 0 which don't work, and then three more for when it doesn't equal 0 which work flawlessly. I think I know my problem, the set of if statements under '//A DOES equal 0', can never run. What's wrong with my second set of nested if statements?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double numA = 0;
    double numB = 0;
    double numC = 0;
    int rootOne = 0;
    int rootTwo = 0;

    // User inputs roots

    cout << "Program computes and prints the real roots of a quadratic polynomial a*x^2 + b*x + c." << endl;
    cout << "Enter three real numbers a, b, c, seperated by spaces:";
    cin >> numA >> numB >> numC;

    //Calculating the Roots; (-b + sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 *a) and (-b - sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 *a)
    rootOne = (-numB + sqrt(numB * numB - 4 * numA * numC)) / (2 * numA);
    rootTwo = (-numB - sqrt(numB * numB - 4 * numA * numC)) / (2 * numA);

    // A doesn't equal 0
    if (numA != 0) {
        if ((numB * numB) - (4 * numA * numC) > 0) {
            cout << "The quadratic polynomial " << numA << "*x^2 + " << numB << "*x + " << numC << " has two distinct real roots" << endl;
            cout << "root 1 = " << rootOne << " root2 = " << rootTwo << endl;

        } else if ((numB * numB) - (4 * numA * numC) == 0) {
            cout << "The quadratic polynomial " << numA << "*x^2 + " << numB << "*x + " << numC << " has two equal real roots" << endl;
            cout << "root 1 = root2 = " << rootTwo << endl;

        } else if ((numB * numB) - (4 * numA * numC) < 0) {
            cout << "The quadratic polynomial " << numA << "*x^2 + " << numB << "*x + " << numC << " has two complex roots" << endl;
        }
    }

    //A does equal 0
    if (numA == 0) {
        if ((numB == 0) && (numC != 0)) {
            cout << "No roots for the constand function of " << numC << endl;
        } else if ((numB == 0) && (numC == 0)) {
            cout << "No roots for the degenerate case of 0 = 0." << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "The only root for the linear case of " << numA << "*x^2 + " << numB << "*x + " << numC << "is: " << numB << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using your debugger is purposed to find the issue, Stack Overflow mainly is not.

Comment: Yeah, our teacher never showed us how to use a debugger, I don't understand what it's telling me.

Comment: Leave that course, your teacher is a bloody moron.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Calm down.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I've got my own opinions what should be taught in  c++ basic courses, teaching to debug is a very basic skill that should be taught. Anyways, I more meant the OP is blaming their teacher, instead of research themselves, and do something what's beyond the course materials.

Comment: ...my teacher is kind of a goof though. I'm not blaming him though, I was more asking if I was nesting statements correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoops:

```
if (numA =! 0) {
```

Here you're *setting* `numA`, to `!0` (which is `true`, then converted to `1` for the assignment).

It's the same as:

```
if (numA = !0) {
```

So it's no surprise that your subsequent `if` statement is "being ignored": the condition no longer matches.

If you'd turned your compiler warnings on, you'd have received a message like:

> warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value

…and then you wouldn't have to <strike>guess what's going on</strike> ask us to fix your code for you.

**The "not equal to" operator is `!=`, not `=!`.**

Comment: I don't get it, should it be: if (numA != 0)? because neither made a difference.

Comment: What don't you "get"? How is this confusing or ambiguous? You wrote the symbols in the wrong order in your code. I don't know how to make that any clearer.

Comment: Ahh okay, I guess my browser just wasn't showing your whole comment, I will go back and check it. Thanks

Comment: Then you have another bug. You need to narrow it down, by stepping through your code operation by operation.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I guess thanks for trying to help...and then insulting me, I never did learn if I nested my statements right or not but whatever. I ended up just rewriting my first nested statements and used Logical Operators like I did at the bottom. So my new code just has all six in one big nest and it worked!

> The "not equal to" operator is !=, not =!

I actually thought I was doing it right before I came here so I did learn something anyway so thanks to that person, as such, you win the best answer!

Comment: Nobody was "insulting" you.